# Why does binary_search() and find() work differently here?

Tags: c++, stl, binary-search, stdvector

If I run the following code, I get the error as ****prog.cpp:7:39: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘bool’ and ‘std::vector::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector >}’)
if(binary_search(v.begin(),v.end(),3) == v.end()) cout<<"not found";****

But if I use find() instead of binary_search() I get the result as expected.
Both these functions return an iterator only, But why are they acting differently in this situation?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  vector < int >v = { 1, 2, 3, 5 };
  
  if (binary_search (v.begin (), v.end (), 3) == v.end ())
    cout << "not found";
  else
    cout << "found";
}
```

Comment: Please check what [`std::binary_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) really returns.

Comment: Unrelated: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)
 and [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::find` and `std::binary_search` do different things.

- `std::find` returns an iterator to the found element (or `end()` if it's not found). It does not require the range to be ordered.
- `std::binary_search` returns a `bool`, `true` or `false`. It requires the range to be ordered.

If you'd like a combination of both a binary search algorithm *and* finding the actual element(s) that matches, you can use [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound), [`std::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) or [`std::equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range). I'll give an example using `std::equal_range`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main () {
    std::vector v = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 5 };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << std::binary_search (v.begin(), v.end(), 3) << '\n' // prints true
        << std::binary_search (v.begin(), v.end(), 4) << '\n' // prints false
    ;

    auto[first, last] = std::equal_range(v.begin(), v.end(), 3);
    
    if(first != last) std::cout << "found\n";    // prints found
    else std::cout << "not found\n";
    
    for(;first != last; ++first) std::cout << *first << '\n'; // prints 3 twice
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YnqsdM)